# Combine two grids with a small area of overlapping pixels to a new raster in QGIS/SAGA

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic, gdal-merge

The first grid is 1 byte and the second is 2 byte.

The new raster should have a **blended transition**.

How can i do this?

Comment: is this a test?

Comment: how do u mean that? but no, ive tried to merge these grids and transformed the second grid to 1 byte, too. but it didnt worked well.

Comment: I was kidding since you put "Hint"... anyway, a transition is not something you can automate as far as I know. Combining using QGIS > Raster > Miscellaneous >  Merge doesn't contain an option for a 'blend' mode...hmmm...

Comment: i thought of a function like "mosaic to new raster" in arcgis. the result of merging in qgis is a "destroyed" new raster. it couldnt handle the overlapping.

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @underdark: u have to imagine 2 satellite images from the same date. one in the north and one in the south and they dont border on each other perfectly. the image in the south overlapps the image in the north. i wanted to merge them to have a compounded satellite image. it doesnt matter if the overlapped part remains after merging. its not necessary to account the overlapped part e.g as mean of the pixel values or something..

Answer (score 3):

Try QGIS' Saga Plugin > Grid Tools > Mosaick raster layers.

You can combine a number of rasters and classify overlapping areas with blending, feathering, min and max values.